# How to monitor the complete network through Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, nms, opennms

I want to use Python to monitor the complete network, if the route or link goes up/down will get the notification.
I found a few packages like lanscan, but I’m not sure that will work fine or not.
Basically, I want to use python same as NMS (Network management system). Please suggest to me some good frameworks or packages.

Answer (score 0):

Pure python-based monitoring solutions are not really scalable as python at the core is pretty slow compared to something like c and multiprocessing is not native. Your best bet would be to use an opensource solution like Zabbix or cacti and use python API to interact with the data